# ASP.NET control with jquery in separate .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have just wrote a jQuery voting script which is working fine if i leave the code within the header of the page.  However I'm looking to move it to a separate .js file and then just include this .js at the top of the page. For some reason when i do this i get an exception error occurs on the `<asp:loginview runat="server">` control.

Can anyone advise how to get round this?  My code is below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".voteup").live("click", function () {

        <asp:LoginView runat="server">
            <LoggedInTemplate>

// if user is logged in, allow them to vote

</LoggedInTemplate>
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have the asp controls in a separate js file. If you want this separation, you will need to think about your control flow and adjust your page design and js accordingly.